# Active Survey Modification

Tags: google-forms

I have a live survey via Google Forms.  I want to edit one of the multiple choice questions.  What will happen to the existing data?  Will I lose the previous answers?  Is it safe to modify one of the multiple choice questions?

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any change download the responses. If you edit/remove one option, unless you enable `Other`, I think that you will not be able to see who choose it directly on the form, but it will be kept on the response repository. Not sure what will happen if you change more that one option.